# Any way to setup LDAP server over secure connection on Perl?

Tags: perl, ldap

Currently I am using Net::LDAP::Server to setup my server but it is not secure enough.
Is there any module or method so that I can setup a LDAP server over TLS or other secure connection?

I just found many information about how to connect to a secure ldap server, but cant found how to setup a secure ldap server.
Can anyone give some advices?

Comment: For anyone stumbling across this old question it looks like putting `stunnel` in front of the `Net::LDAP::Server` perl process might be the best option.
https://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/archived/LDAP-Implementation-HOWTO/ssl.html

Answer (score 1):

How does an LDAPS connection work

LDAPS is an unofficial protocol. It is to LDAP what HTTPS is to HTTP, namely the exact same protocol (but in this case LDAPv2 or LDAPv3) running over a secured SSL ("Secure Socket Layer") connection to port 636 (by default).

Not all servers will be configured to listen for LDAPS connections, but if they do, it will commonly be on a different port from the normal plain text LDAP port.

Using LDAPS can potentially solve the vulnerabilities described above, but you should be aware that simply "using" SSL is not a magic bullet that automatically makes your system "secure".

First of all, LDAPS can solve the problem of verifying that you are connected to the correct server. When the client and server connect, they perform a special SSL 'handshake', part of which involves the server and client exchanging cryptographic keys, which are described using X.509 certificates. If the client wishes to confirm that it is connected to the correct server, all it needs to do is verify the server's certificate which is sent in the handshake. This is done in two ways:

check that the certificate is signed (trusted) by someone that you trust, and that the certificate hasn't been revoked. For instance, the server's certificate may have been signed by Verisign (www.verisign.com), and you decide that you want to trust Verisign to sign legitimate certificates.
check that the least-significant cn RDN in the server's certificate's DN is the fully-qualified hostname of the hostname that you connected to when creating the LDAPS object. For example if the server is , then the RDN to check is cn=ldap.example.com.
You can do this by using the cafile and capath options when creating a Net::LDAPS object, and by setting the verify option to 'require'.

To prevent hackers 'sniffing' passwords and other information on your connection, you also have to make sure the encryption algorithm used by the SSL connection is good enough. This is also something that gets decided by the SSL handshake - if the client and server cannot agree on an acceptable algorithm the connection is not made.

Net::LDAPS will by default use all the algorithms built into your copy of OpenSSL, except for ones considered to use "low" strength encryption, and those using export strength encryption. You can override this when you create the Net::LDAPS object using the 'ciphers' option.

Once you've made the secure connection, you should also check that the encryption algorithm that is actually being used is one that you find acceptable. Broken servers have been observed in the field which 'fail over' and give you an unencrypted connection, so you ought to check for that.

How does LDAP and TLS work

SSL is a good solution to many network security problems, but it is not a standard. The IETF corrected some defects in the SSL mechanism and published a standard called RFC 2246 which describes TLS ("Transport Layer Security"), which is simply a cleaned up and standardized version of SSL.

You can only use TLS with an LDAPv3 server. That is because the standard (RFC 2830) for LDAP and TLS requires that the normal LDAP connection (ie., on port 389) can be switched on demand from plain text into a TLS connection. The switching mechanism uses a special extended LDAP operation, and since these are not legal in LDAPv2, you can only switch to TLS on an LDAPv3 connection.

So the way you use TLS with LDAPv3 is that you create your normal LDAPv3 connection using Net::LDAP::new(), and then you perform the switch using Net::LDAP::start_tls(). The start_tls() method takes pretty much the same arguments as Net::LDAPS::new(), so check above for details.

Comment: I think this is about the LDAP client connection method. It didn't mention that the server how to accept a tls.

Answer (score 1):

Well, perhaps LDAPS is not an RFC but to say it is not a standard or secure is certainly a stretch.

LDAPS is supported by ALL LDAP Server Vendors.
LDAPS is at least as secure as HTTPS.
As with ALL SSL (or TLS) the security weak points are how the certificates are handled.

Certainly LDAPS is more supported by LDAP server vendors and clients than is TLS. Active Directory as one example, does not support TLS. Querying the rootDSE for the supportedExtention 1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.20037 will (should) show if TLS is supported on any particular LDAP server.

We have some examples at:
http://ldapwiki.willeke.com/wiki/Perl%20LDAP%20Samples.